# ajax post with a list value

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i do an Ajax Post with a dropdown list? For example, I choose the first item,  then, the id value of the `li>a` it will be sent to a php page (data.php). Do You Have Any Idea about this ?

[demo here](http://jsbin.com/ajolub/5/edit#preview)

```
<div style="width: 162px;">
    <dl style="" class="dropdown">
        <dt>
            <a class="" id="linkglobal" style="cursor: pointer;"></a>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <ul style="display: none;" id="ulglobal">
                <li><a id="1" href="#">One</a></li> 
                <li><a id="2" href="#">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
<div>
```

thanks

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker I only know how to make this when i have a <form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("#ulglobal a").click(function(){
    var selectedId=$(this).attr("id");
    $.post("data.php" { id : selectedId },function(data){
      // do whatever with the response.
    });

 });
});
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/nGPw9/2/